# Can I install apache with PHP 5.3.29 on Ubuntu Server 20.04?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

Is there any way to install php version 5.3 that will work with apache? I realy need to run an old application that only uses this version.

I already installed php according to this instruction but apache does not see it:

```
cd /tmp && wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
tar -xvf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
cd php-5.3.29
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I would recommend in the strongest terms against running PHP 5.3 for anything public facing. It's ten years old, hasn't been supported in seven, and has **well known, highly publicized** major security flaws ☠️.

You will be hacked within days, if not hours.

As for your setup, I strongly suspect you're not going to find version of `libapache2-mod-php` compatible with both modern Apache and PHP 5.3 - you're going to have a bad time. You can probably dig up and manually compile an old version of Apache.

If you *absolutely must*, you can use a pre-built setup with Docker. You'll get a *smidgen* more safety from containerizing your application, but note you can and should never depend on containers for security purposes. Breakouts are extremely common.

```
docker pull php:5.3-apache
```